# masm x86 Assembly Is it possible to check if an address is allocated or not?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

In masm, you can statically allocate memory using the .DATA, and .DATA? directives, and that is great, but what if I needed to allocate a block of memory dynamically? Lets say that I wanted to create a DWORD with the value 10 in dynamically allocated memory. One theory is that I could run through a range of addresses, check if they are allocated or not, and if not then allocate the address and use it to store the DWORD in. But there is only one problem; I do not know how to check if an address is allocated or not. :(

```
Make_Dword PROC
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDI
PUSH EBX
MOV EBX, [EBP - 08h] ;EBP - 08h is the dword value
;Iterate through memory addresses and check if one is unallocated, if so
; use it to store the dword value in, finally return the newly allocated
; address of the dword in memory.
MOV EAX, [the newly allocated address of the dword]
POP EBX
POP EDI
POP ESI
MOV ESP, EBP
POP EBP
Make_Dword ENDP

PUSH DWORD PTR 0Ah
CALL Make_Dword
```

Comment: You need to ask the operating system to give you some memory. You can't just go around poking in the address space, you won't find any valid memory unless you ask for it, because it's not mapped.

Comment: Then that changes the question to: How can I ask the operating System for memory? is there an Interrupt for that or something? :)

Comment: That all depends on the operating system.

Comment: and whichever memory mapped is, is either writeable, or not (depending on the OS, how it did set it up for your app). There's no such thing as "allocated" memory in asm. That's high-level logic construct, managed by some memory manager (OS), on bare HW without OS there's just the memory chip, and you can write where you wish.

Comment: I am using masm, so Windows. :)

Comment: When I say iterate I don't exactly mean iterate like one would iterate through an array, I mean start at address 0x00 for example, and work your way up to address 0xFF for example, checking to see if they are allocated or not.

Comment: If your code is an application that must run on a modern OS, you can not simply poke memory and check if it is allocated (and assigned to your application). You are generally not allowed to access memory that does not belong to your application/process. The OS will not allow it. Allocated memory can be obtained from the OS. High level languages often have a suballocator, which obtains memory from the OS and hands it out piecemeal to the "user". Such suballocators can have different strategies to provide memory of a certain required size to the "user", to mark memory as free or allocated, etc.

Comment: Well how can I communicate to the OS and say "hey, give me memory for a dword!"

Comment: On Windows, you call the [`HeapAlloc` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing my response to see if maybe I can clarify.  If you have a data directive, can you just allocate a static size block of memory with it? e.g.

.DATA
    poolOfDwords DWORD 1000

Then, just initialize them to values that you know you cannot get (-1 maybe?).  Then, when you need to "allocate" a DWORD, you can just iterate through the list for the first entry that is -1 (unallocated) and use it.  You can return the offset to that location if you need to use it.

Hopefully that helps clarify my idea.

Comment: Are you suggesting that he randomly just start using some chunk of memory with that, "Set the buffer to -1 and search for the first slot that isn't that value?"  That's a horrible idea.

Comment: Oh, I was suggesting that he create a static sized block of data (maybe with the .DATA directive) and then initialize it to -1.  Then when he wants to "allocate" an entry, he just search for the first entry without -1 -- just a simple data pool I guess.

Comment: The best approach IMHO would just be to invoke malloc to allocate the data he needs or push the data on the stack if he only needs the data in the local context.

Comment: thank you, although your idea of initializing the buffer to -1 was not exactly what I was hoping for, this is the  most useful answer :)

Comment: @mikebayko well, it depends how much memory you expect to need. If few bytes, like hundreds or thousands, then you can either create fixed size buffer in `.data` for example 100kB long, and work over it (like Jon suggest, using some marker value to distinguish between free/used, or having additional data table with usage data in it). Or up to few kB size you can "allocate" stack space (by `esp -= <size>;` and managing that part of memory as data block), but for few MB-GB just check the windows platform API, what are the options (I have no idea, I don't use windows for a decade+).

Comment: @mikebayko and if you know C or C++, the easiest way may be to link your asm against the default clib, and use `malloc`/`free` to handle dynamic allocation. As writing your own memory manager is a bit of hassle, and writing good memory manager is actually quite a task, that's why there exists several different allocators as libraries (you may even use one of them, if default clib is not good enough for you).